# C++ - segmentation fault on second binary search

Tags: c++, vector, valgrind

I have a class `ledger`, whose instances are supposed to store instances of a member class `company` in two vectors `combyID` and `combyname`, sorted by two different criteria - ID and name (both are strings). The vectors start out empty, so instead of sorting them after each new addition of an instance of the member class, a customized binary search methods `binsID` and `binsName` search the vectors for the element to be added and if the element isn't found, it is inserted in the vectors. The `insert()` position is defined by the `idx` value, modified by the binary search method.

The problem lies within the method `NewCo`, which calls both binary search methods and eventually inserts the element to the vectors. When the program is run with more than just one `NewCo` call in the `main` function, `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error is given. The error doesn't appear either if the `binsID` method isn't called or the `insert()` isn't called on `combyID` (omitting the insertion to that vector). I am posting both the code and the valgrind analysis.

The code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class ledger
{
  public:
    bool NewCo (string name, string ID)
    {
        unsigned int idx_id = 0, idx_name = 0;
        bool found1 = binsID(combyID, idx_id, ID);  //line 14
        bool found2 = binsName(combyname, idx_name, name);
        if (found1 == false && found2 == false)
        {
            company co;
            co.co_name = name;
            co.co_id = ID;
            combyID.insert(combyID.begin() + idx_id, co);
            combyname.insert(combyname.begin() + idx_name, co);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
  private:
      class company
      {
      public:
          string co_name;
          string co_id;
      };
      vector <company> combyID;
      vector <company> combyname;
      bool binsName(vector <company> vek, unsigned int & idx, string val)
      {
          if (vek.size() == 0) return false; 
          unsigned int begin = 0, end = vek.size() - 1, mid;
          while(begin <= end)
          {
              mid = (begin + end) / 2;
              idx = mid;
              if (vek[mid].co_name == val) 
              {
                  idx = mid;
                  return true;
              }
              else if (val < vek[mid].co_name)
                  end = mid - 1;
              else
                  begin = mid + 1;
          }
        if (vek[idx].co_name < val) idx++;
        return false;
      }
    bool binsID(vector <company> vek, unsigned int & idx, string val)
      {
        if (vek.size() == 0) return false; 
          unsigned int begin = 0, end = vek.size() - 1, mid;
          while(begin <= end)
          {
              mid = (begin + end) / 2;
              idx = mid;
              if (vek[mid].co_id == val)  //line 66
              {
                  idx = mid;
                  return true;
              }
              else if (val < vek[mid].co_id)
                  end = mid - 1;
              else
                  begin = mid + 1;
          }
        if (vek[idx].co_id < val) idx++;
        return false;
      }
};

int main ( void )
{
  ledger b1;
  b1.NewCo( "ABC", "123.456.789" );
  b1.NewCo( "DEF", "123.456" );  //line 85

  return 0;
}
```

Valgrind:

```
==6775== Command: ./a.out -g
==6775== 
==6775== Invalid read of size 8
==6775==    at 0x4F597B0: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==6775==    by 0x401C2A: __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<char>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==<char>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:4913)
==6775==    by 0x40177B: ledger::binsID(std::vector<ledger::company, std::allocator<ledger::company> >, unsigned int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (main.cpp:66)
==6775==    by 0x40138B: ledger::NewCo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (main.cpp:14)
==6775==    by 0x40109E: main (main.cpp:85)
==6775==  Address 0x2005ab5d68 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6775== 
==6775== 
==6775== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6775==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x2005AB5D68
==6775==    at 0x4F597B0: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==6775==    by 0x401C2A: __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<char>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==<char>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.h:4913)
==6775==    by 0x40177B: ledger::binsID(std::vector<ledger::company, std::allocator<ledger::company> >, unsigned int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (main.cpp:66)
==6775==    by 0x40138B: ledger::NewCo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (main.cpp:14)
==6775==    by 0x40109E: main (main.cpp:85)
==6775==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6775==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6775==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6775==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6775==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==6775== 
==6775== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6775==     in use at exit: 72,896 bytes in 4 blocks
==6775==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 0 frees, 72,896 bytes allocated
==6775== 
==6775== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6775==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6775==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6775==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6775==    still reachable: 72,896 bytes in 4 blocks
==6775==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6775== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6775== 
==6775== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6775== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Please return true/false from a bool function instead of 1/0. Also you seem to have rewritten [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) twice.

Comment: @Borgleader the t/f is my bad. I have tried using lower_bound, but writing my own just seemed more intuitive.

Comment: end is 0 and you subtract one from it on line 72, but because it's  unsigned it becomes 2^32-1 and you fail to break from the loop.  Make being/end int's instead of unsigned ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to review your algorithms in both `binsName()` and `binsID()` methods.

For your second pass, the statement:

```
end = mid - 1;
```

is producing an `end` value of `-1` (or in this case, `UINT_MAX` since you're using unsigned integers) as the value of `mid` is `0`.